# Приложение вылетает при setOnClickListener

Tags: kotlin, activity, setonclicklistener

Помогите пожалуйста, код ошибки не научился ещё читать, но кажется, что я не могу закончить переход activity в другую activity.

В onDestroy поставил null так, как вылетала на других версиях api ошибка ormemory, код полностью рабочий на более ранних версиях api, на более поздних не срабатывает setonclicklistener и вылетает. Пожалуйста, подскажите в чём мог допустить ошибку и если можно направьте.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val networkConnection = NetworkConnection(applicationContext)
        networkConnection.observe(this, Observer { isConnected ->
            if (isConnected){
                Connected_activitymenu.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                Disconnected_activitymenu.visibility = View.GONE
            }else{
                Connected_activitymenu.visibility = View.GONE
                Disconnected_activitymenu.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        })

        Button1.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, menu1_menu::class.java)
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            startActivity(intent)

        }
        Button2.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,, menu2_menu::class.java)
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true)
        finish()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        Button1.setOnClickListener(null)
        Button2.setOnClickListener(null)
        super.onDestroy()
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/fon">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Connected_activitymenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/logo"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/Button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/menu1" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/Button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/menu2" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Disconnected_activitymenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/MenuImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/noconnection"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Код ошибки:

```
2020-07-23 16:20:19.767 4145-4145/Название проекта E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: Название проекта, PID: 4145
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {Название проекта.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NetworkCallback was not registered
        at android.app.ActivityThread.callActivityOnStop(ActivityThread.java:4858)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4829)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:4903)
        at android.app.servertransaction.StopActivityItem.execute(StopActivityItem.java:40)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NetworkCallback was not registered
        at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:52)
        at android.net.ConnectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(ConnectivityManager.java:4185)
        at desspace.net.festcard.NetworkConnection.onInactive(NetworkConnection.kt:42)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$ObserverWrapper.activeStateChanged(LiveData.java:421)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver.onStateChanged(LiveData.java:376)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:361)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.backwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:316)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:334)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:145)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:131)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment.dispatch(ReportFragment.java:123)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment.onStop(ReportFragment.java:102)
        at android.app.Fragment.performStop(Fragment.java:2719)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1365)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1581)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1642)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchMoveToState(FragmentManager.java:3052)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStop(FragmentManager.java:3022)
        at android.app.FragmentController.dispatchStop(FragmentController.java:228)
        at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:8207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.callActivityOnStop(ActivityThread.java:4850)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4829) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:4903) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.StopActivityItem.execute(StopActivityItem.java:40) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Насколько я могу судить, проблема связана с `networkConnection`, а не с `setOnClickListener`

Comment: Спасибо @Alex_Skvortsov, дальше додумаю, предполагал, но не думал, что такое может произойти на api 29-30, на всех остальных нормально api работала.

Comment: А что за класс `NetworkConnection`?

Comment: У меня есть NetworkConnection.kt помимо других activity и он даёт проверку, подключен ли интернет или нет, wi-fi или мобильный интернет, если да, то отображается Connected_activitymenu.visibility = View.VISIBLE, если нет то GONE, при разных устройствах api код свой. И в манифесте также должен быть <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Вот тут косяк `desspace.net.festcard.NetworkConnection.onInactive(NetworkConnection.kt:42)`, пытаетесь отменить регистрацию колбека, который и не был регистрирован. А зануления обработчиков кнопок -- лишнее.